# Transpose vertical data to horizontal format in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a series of data in Excel that I'm attempting to graph, but I'm unsure how to either setup the graph to display the information in the grouping that I want, or how to create a formula, or second table and aggregate the data into the desired format.

Exhibit A:

```
+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 |
+---------+---------+
| 1995 A  | 5       |
| 1995 B  | 6       |
| 1996 A  | 7       |
| 1996 B  | 8       |
| 1997 A  | 9       |
| 1997 B  | 10      |
| .... A  | xx      |
| .... B  | xx      |
+---------+---------+
```

I wish to either transpose the data to a second table to something like this:

Exhibit B:

```
+---------+------+------+------+------+
| Column1 | 1995 | 1996 | 1997 | etc. |
+---------+------+------+------+------+
| A       | 6    | 7    | 9    | xx   |
| B       | 6    | 8    | 10   | xx   |
+---------+------+------+------+------+
```

Or graph exhibit A to show a chart to what the exhibit B data would display if you were to create a chart from that data.
I can create the column and row headers manually, but I need to by able to create a formula (unless you have a better idea) for the data to those headers.

NOTE: After checking SO Meta, Excel Formula questions are best asked on StackOverflow.

Comment: I would say split the first column in two and use a dynamic graph/table

Comment: @SJuan76, split the first column in two? How do you mean? Though my example is small, in my actual data, there are currently 1350 rows. If I'm able to solve, it would translate to 8 rows and 18 columns.

Comment: A and B in a separate column that the year...

Comment: @SJuan76, ah, I see... split data using 'Text to Columns'. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split column 1, then use a pivot table (Insert -> PivotTable).

[image]

I hope this is close enough to what you need.